# Вывод всех потомков из таблицы при связи ManyToMany Django ORM

Tags: python, база-данных, django, orm

Есть две таблицы

```
catalog_product:

id |name
10  prod3
9   prod2
8   prod1
11  prod5

catalog_productcategory: (из либы mptt, модель дерева)

id | name       | lft | rght | tree_id | level | parent_id
2    root1         1     6        1        0      null
3    subroot1      2     5        1        1      2
5    subsubroot1   3     4        1        2      3
6    root2         1     4        2        0      null
7    subroot2      2     3        2        1      6


Связующая таблица catalog_product_category:

id | product_id | productcategory_id
7    10           2
8    9            3
9    8            5
10   11           7
```

дерево catalog_productcategory выглядит следующим образом:

```
root1
  subroot1
    subsubroot1
root2
  subroot2
```

Мои две модели со связью многие ко многим

```
class ProductCategory(MPTTModel):
    """категории продуктов"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)        
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['name']  


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_products(self):
        return self.category_products.all()


class Product(models.Model):
    """Продукты"""
   
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1024)    
    category = models.ManyToManyField(ProductCategory, related_name="category_products")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Я хочу получать при обращении к root1 не только продукты, которые находятся в этой корневой категории, но и все продукты которые находятся в дочерних категориях, а при обращении к дочерней категории, только то что находится в ней.

```
def getiing(request):

    categories = ProductCategory.objects.prefetch_related('category_products')
    stores = []
    for cat in categories:
        products = [{'product_id':  product.id, 'product_name':  product.name} for product in cat.get_products()]
        if not products:
            pass
        else:
            stores.append({'category_id': cat.id, 'category_name': cat.name, 'products': products})

    print(*stores, sep='\n')
```

Сейчас я получаю это:

```
{'category_id': 2, 'category_name': 'root1', 'products': [{'product_id': 10, 'product_name': 'prod3'}]}
```

А должен получить примерно так:

Фильтр по root1

```
{'category_id': 2, 'category_name': 'root1', 'products': [{'product_id': 10, 'product_name': 'prod3'}, {'product_id': 9, 'product_name': 'prod2'}, {'product_id': 8, 'product_name': 'prod1'}]}
```

Фильтр по subroot1

```
{'category_id': 3, 'category_name': 'subroot1', 'products': [{'product_id': 10, 'product_name': 'prod3'}, {'product_id': 9, 'product_name': 'prod2'}]}
```

Категории могут быть такими

```
   root1 
      subroot1_1 
         subsubroot1_1_1
            subsubsubroot1_1_1_1 
         subsubroot1_1_2
      subroot1_2 
         subsubroot1_2_1
   root2
      subroot2_1
```

Comment: а подкатегории могут иметь в себе подкатегории?

Comment: да, подкатегории могут иметь несколько подкатегорий

Comment: @АндрейИванов перефразирую ответ: "уровень вложенности подкатегорий вообще не ограничен, так как в модели просто стоит рекурсивная связь на саму себя". Так будет правильнее

Comment: уровень вложенности не ограничен (но по сути мне более 5 уровней не нужно)  в модели категорий каждый parent ссылается на родителя в этой же таблице и так по нисходящей.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, всего одна строчка кода делает всё то, что мне нужно. шок и боль

```
    Product.objects.filter(
category__in=ProductCategory.objects.get(id=5).get_descendants(include_self=True)
)
```